# HTML - CSS / how to make the child divs height responsive to the parents

Tags: html, css, height, parent-child

Example Issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4y5rqoxr/

```
.outer {
    min-width: 100%;
}
#bgvid {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:33%;
    height:100%; /*HOW TO MAKE THIS 100% OF THE PARENT DIV? NOT 100% VIEWPORT*/
    background:#FF0004;

}
```

Hey guys, im trying to make a text box overlay a video Background and adopt the video divs height? any help ive poked around a bunch with no luck!

Zak

Answer (score 1):

You need a height declaration and `position:relative;` on your parent element.

```
.outer {
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

See Snippet.

```css
.outer {
    min-width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
#bgvid {
    position: relative;
 min-width: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: -100;
 background-size: cover;
}
.inner{
    position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width:33%;
    height:100%; /*HOW TO MAKE THIS 100% OF THE PARENT DIV? NOT 100% VIEWPORT*/
    background:#FF0004;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
    <video autoplay  poster="http://placehold.it/1600x900" id="bgvid" loop>
    <source src="" type="video/webm">
    </video>
    <div class="inner">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, i can see this working in Fiddle, but couldn't get a solution working in Dreamweaver, so i made a new project copied the HTML and CSS as is and still no cigar?

Comment: okiee so i made a new site, used same code, and this one works. no idea what previous problem was but its all working now SUPER THANKS!

Comment: Glad you got it working. The important thing to remember is that the parent element must have a height declaration for the children elements to use percentage based height measurements. Also, you may want to mark this answer as accepted so other people don't spend time trying to solve it.